# Multiple Regression in R with y as a Factor

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, lm

I have a data set that rates customer satisfaction based on three options:

Recommend
Neutral
Not satisfied
I understand those may not be the best options but that's what I have to work with.

Another caveat is that I must build the model in R so I'm trying to determine how to build a multiple regression model when y is a factor.

Once I understand that I want to use a stepwise approach to determine the variables I should use based on the code below:

```
install.packages("MASS")
library("MASS")
model <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=DATASET)
step <- stepAIC(model, direction = "both")
summary(step)
```

I don't have any issues when y is numeric, but I don't think I can just arbitrarily assign values to the customer satisfaction by making Recommend == 1, Neutral == 2, and Not Satisfied == 3.

I was thinking about creating three new variables called Recommend, Neutral and Not Satisfied and assigning 1s under columns where the feedback applies to a customer and a 0 when it doesn't.

If that is an acceptable approach I'm stuck trying to determine how to incorporate all three variables into my model since all of them represent the output I'm trying to predict.

Thank you for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: You should try logistic regression.

Comment: You should try ordinal logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as the comments say, you've got two primary choices depending on how you want to conceptualize your dependent variable. If you want to keep its ordered structure and treat it as a ordinal measure then you can do a proportional odds model (ordinal logistic regression). If you just treat them as separate levels with no ordering then you can just do a multinomial logistic regression.

Mutlinomial logistic regression can be done with `VGAM` package.

```
    library(VGAM)
    some.model<-vglm(DV~IV1+IV2+IV3)family=multinomial(refLevel=whatever.it.is),data=my.data)
```

The interpretation is like binary logistic regression with more levels. I.e. It gives you the log odds of being in a level compared to the reference level of the DV, for each unit increase in the IV.

You have to take the exponential of the betas before you interpret it, and the interpretation is in odds not in raw values. So for example, if you get a $\beta_{IV1}=0.7$, then $e^{\beta_{IV1}}=e^{0.7}=2.01$ means being the effect of a one unit increase in IV 1 on the the odds of someone being in level 2 (of the DV) compared to level 1 is a 101% increase, or around twice the odds. So, in your case as IV1 increases the chances of the customer being "neutral" compared to "not satisfied" is increased by 100%. And so on, for your other levels of the DV.

If you want to preserve the ordered structure of your dependent variable, the `VGAM` package will also do proportional odds models.

```
    model1<-vglm(DV~IV1+IV2_IV3, family=cumulative(parallel=T),data=my.data)
```

First start off by assuming the different levels have proportional odds, this assumes that the IV affects the levels of the DV equally. So each level will have a different intercept but only one $\beta$ per DV. These models capture the ordered nature of the DV, by fitting a cumulative odds model. You interpret by taking the exponential of the $\beta$ again, and this time it's the effect of one unit increase of IV1 is to in/decrease the cumulative odds *ratio* (compared to if you had not increased the IV) of being in level 2 *or lower* by whatever percent. The effect of IV1 on level 3 *or lower* is the same. But that doesn't mean the levels of the DV have the same odds because remember they have different intercepts.

But then sometimes the IV has a different effect on the levels of the DV and so the odds are not proportional. You can check it by fitting the model and saying `parallel=F`. To know whether the assumption is violated or not, compare the fit of the models using a log likelihood ratio test `2*(logLik(model2)-logLik(model1))` which is distributed $\chi^2_{p(k-2)}$ where P is the number of parameters and k is number of levels of the DV. If setting `parallel=F` leads to a significantly better fit, then the assumption is broken. In fact, you can say only a *specific* IV has non proportional odds between levels of the DV, while the other IVs *do* have proportional odds by saying `parallel=F~IV1`

If the odds are non proportional, there will be different $\beta$'s for each level of the DV. Now, after taking exponential of $\beta$, the interpretation is the effect of a one unit increase in IV1 increases the odds ratio (compared to no increase in IV1) of the person being in level 2 *or lower* by this much. A one unit increase in IV1 increases the odds ratio (compared to no increase in IV1) of the person being in level 3 *or lower* by that much.

Which approach you take depends on how you conceptualize your DV, but i do admit the multinomial approach is slightly less confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the long winded post, i just wanted to write how to interpret them in case you were not familiar with them at all, because I never know the knowledge of people asking questions. At least with the names of the models you can look up more info on your own.