# Regression methods for ordered categorical data with more than 2 levels

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution

I am dealing with an Outcome Variable `y` which is categorical (0,1,2,3) and ordered.

My question is what type of regression models can I try for such a dataset ? I know ordinal regression applies to ordered data with 2 levels and multinational regression is applicable when y is categorical and more than 2 levels but not ordered.

So I am curious which regression models should I try in this situation(y is categorical , with more than 2 levels and ordered) ?

Comment: Try proportional odds model, similar to logistic regression, can incorporate more than 2 levels and ordered response variable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit

Comment: I gave a pretty long winded answer to a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379715/multiple-regression-in-r-with-y-as-a-factor/379755#379755) including how to interpret such a model.

Comment: @HuyPhamPham, TheLonic, user158565, all three of you seem to suggest Orderd Logit Model which seem to fit the underlying process related to my y variable in my data. Many thanks I am going to try this approach.