# Which regression models and software are appropriate for nominal variable with 4 response categories)?

Tags: regression, categorical-data

please guide me about the appropriate model of regression analysis when the dependent variable (with four response categories) as well as the independent variables are categorical (nominal level)  and can i use SPSS to run the regression analysis appropriate for this type of data?

Comment: A nominal variable with 4 responses categories cannot be normally distributed.  Can you tell us a bit more about what you are trying to do and give us some more information about your data?  Be as specific as possible with relevant information.

Comment: This uses R code, but you can just type in how to do the models in spss. The answer has instructions on how to interpret the models too.https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379715/multiple-regression-in-r-with-y-as-a-factor/379755#379755