# Which regression should be used when both dependent and independent variables are nominal? All have multiple classes

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

The aim is to find which team will win the game based on head to head data.
All the variables are nominal and have more than 2 classes. For now, I have coded them as dummy variables and have performed an SLR to get a basic idea of how the result will turn out to be.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379715/multiple-regression-in-r-with-y-as-a-factor/379755#379755 This might be useful

Comment: @HuyPham Thanks for the link.The model became way too compex with multinomial. So, I changed the dependent variable to binary form and implemented binomial logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple categorical variables then I would use a log-linear model as these are easier to implement than multinomial models.

If you are working in R then [this](https://data.library.virginia.edu/an-introduction-to-loglinear-models/) is a good straight forward tutorial on how to do this and explaining how and why you might want to implement these over other models.

Comment: Thank you, the link is really helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type of logistic regression. If your dependent variable is binary then you can use binary logit model whereas if you have more than 2 categories on your dependent variable, you can use multinomial logit.

Comment: I think you mean any type of binomial regression - logisitc regression is a binomial regression with a logit link. The choice of link can also be important - logit is typically more interpretable, but if you are interested in prediction complementary log-log can be more useful as it copes better with over-dispersion.